# Quiz: Save input values

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a quiz in Javascript and it's going pretty well. However I stumbled upon one thing I didn't manage to fix. I want that if the user navigates back to his previously chosen answers are stored and displayed in each of the radio buttons. The point is, is that when the user goes to the next question, I  set the input values to null, else the last selected answer from the previous question stays active. I'm  in a little learning course, so the only thing I really need is some more explanation on how to go about this little problem. I can show code if needed.

Edit:

Fixed it by adding a new Object where I store all the data which have been put in like this. 
When the user selects the answer the answer will be set like this.

```
this.userAnswers[this.questionId] = answer;
```

Comment: `I can show code if needed.` Always better to show your relevant code than not.

Comment: There is no relevant code. I'm actually asking how to go about this the best way. The code I have doesn't add that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object for all buttons.
Give all the buttons their own unique class or id that is equal to the values in the object:

```
var answers = {
answer1 : '',
answer2 : ''
Etc... }
```

Write to this array, and read from it when you go back.
Assumption due to lack of code: it is all on the same page.